# C# How can detect cyclic references?

Tags: c#

For one given instance of TreeList, how can I check whether or not another instance of TreeList, which is to be added to the first TreeList, contains a (possibly indirect) reference to the first TreeList itself (which would create a cyclic reference)?

For Example:

```
TreeList T1 = new TreeList();
TreeList T2 = new TreeList();
TreeList T3 = new TreeList();
T1.add(T2);
T2.add(T3);
T3.add(T1);
```

Because when I iterrate through this I would get stuck in a loop, because after T3 I would get back to T1. So how can I check if one is already included in the order.

```
class TreeList
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    List<TreeList> items = new List<TreeList>();
    public ReadOnlyCollection<TreeList> Items
    {
        get { return items.AsReadOnly(); }
    }

    public TreeList(string Name)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public void Add(string item)
    {
        items.Add(new TreeList(item));
    }
    public void Add(TreeList subTree)
    {
        items.Add(subTree);
    }
    public override string  ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: But let's say i have T1, T2, T3 and T4. When I Add T4 to T3 and T3 to T2 and T2 to T1. How would I check in Instance T4 if T1 isn't already contained in the row?

Comment: You need to also include how you iterate through them.

Comment: `if(!subTree.Equals(this))` ?

Comment: What about adding visited flag for each node and stop if it was already visited?

Comment: Seems like this is not really about types but more about cyclic references in a tree structure...

Comment: @Zbigniew would be an Optione but it should be possible to add T2 to T1 multiple times but not in a row, so that I don't get a loop.

Answer (score 2):

I think these methods will work:

```
public bool ContainsRecursively(TreeList node)
{
    foreach (TreeList child in items)
        if (child == node || child.ContainsRecursively(node))
            return true;

    return false;
}
public void Add(TreeList tree)
{
    if (this == tree) return; // this tree is 'tree', don't add ourselves!
    if (this.ContainsRecursively(tree)) return; // 'tree' is already in this tree
    if (tree.ContainsRecursively(this)) return; // this tree is already in 'tree'
    items.add(tree);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this recoursive approach:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TreeList T1 = new TreeList("");
    TreeList T2 = new TreeList("");
    TreeList T3 = new TreeList("");

    T1.Add(T2);
    T2.Add(T3);

    bool result = Contains(T1, T2); // test 1- true
    bool result2 = Contains(T2, T1); // test 2 - false
    bool result3 = Contains(T3, T2); // test 3 - false
}

public static bool Contains(TreeList source, TreeList searchedElement)
{
     if (source.Equals(searchedElement) || source.Items.Contains(searchedElement))
         return true;

     foreach (TreeList tList in source.Items)
     {
         if (tList.Items.Count > 0 && Contains(tList, searchedElement))
             return true;
     }

     return false;
 }
```

Comment: Instead of using `Any` you can just use the built-in `Contains` on a collection. It will be much more effective. ie.: `T2.Items.Contains(T1)`

Comment: Thanks @MichaelCoxon, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Beware `Contains(T1, T1)`

Comment: @grek40, updated